# Vaadin Flow: DatePicker setAutoselect(true)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm building a form with Vaadin Flow. I do like to have the ability to step through the elemts of the form using the tab, and on focus I do like to have the content of the textfield selected.

That works perfectly with all the different kind of textfields and textareas, but not with the pickers. Is there a possibility to access the textfield behind and set the autoselect property?

```
setAutoselect(true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1110) for DatePicker autoSelect and it mentions a workaround that is valid if you are using Vaadin 14.

There has been some recent activity and you can add a  reaction to the ticket so that it gets more attention.